# Getting called only on first three numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am getting phone numbers in format **(888) 478-0041**. And I am creating a link for that means if you tap on that phone number, it will automatically make a call. But in this format my call is going only on first three numbers is **(888)**. so what should I do, I am not getting.

I have an string which is coming from a server :

```
<p>Your 2017 F-150 may need an oil change soon. &nbsp;Call&nbsp;</p><b><a href=\"tel:(888) 853-6045\">(888) 853-6045</a></b><p>&nbsp;or <a href=\"tel:(888) 478-0041\">(888) 478-0041</a> click</p><b>&nbsp;here</b><p>&nbsp;to schedule online. &nbsp;Jacob Williams, Service Manager</p>
```

I want to remove any space after tel which comes up to 10 characters in the phone number.

I am using the below code for that.

```
if ([serviceMessage containsString:@"tel:"]) {
     NSUInteger location = [serviceMessage rangeOfString:@"tel:"].location + 4;
     serviceMessage = [serviceMessage substringFromIndex:location];
     [serviceMessage substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11,0)];
     serviceMessage =[serviceMessage substringToIndex:10];
     NSLog(@"New Trimmed string:%@",serviceMessage);
     serviceMessage = [serviceMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
     NSLog(@"Final Trimmed string:%@",serviceMessage);
}
```

Comment: show ur tried code with tap  action also

Comment: just update your question with some snap code that you try for making call

Comment: what is the final output u get in here serviceMessage

Comment: The spaces are not being remove while I want to remove the spaces after tel: only upto 10 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablestring/1412453-replaceoccurrencesofstring) if you just want to replace space within specific range and for multiple searching of `tel:` use `NSRegularExpression`.

```
NSString *serviceMessage = @"<p>Your 2017 F-150 may need an oil change soon. &nbsp;Call&nbsp;</p><b><a href=\"tel:(888) 853-6045\">(888) 853-6045</a></b><p>&nbsp;or <a href=\"tel:(888) 478-0041\">(888) 478-0041</a> click</p><b>&nbsp;here</b><p>&nbsp;to schedule online. &nbsp;Jacob Williams, Service Manager</p>";

NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(tel:)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:serviceMessage options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, serviceMessage.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSUInteger location = wordRange.location + 4;
    serviceMessage = [serviceMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(location, 13)];
}
NSLog(@"%@",serviceMessage);
```

**Output**

```
<p>Your 2017 F-150 may need an oil change soon. &nbsp;Call&nbsp;</p><b><a href="tel:(888)853-6045">(888) 853-6045</a></b><p>&nbsp;or <a href="tel:(888)478-0041">(888) 478-0041</a> click</p><b>&nbsp;here</b><p>&nbsp;to schedule online. &nbsp;Jacob Williams, Service Manager</p>
```

Comment: Hi @Nirav ,But there are two tel; in that what I will have to do for second

Comment: Yes sure, If you will do that then thank you very much for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support

Answer (score 0):

"Mr. Aditya Pandey" have given a very nice and techfull solution. But if you are not more familiar with the iOS concepts and if you find that solution hard, you can also go with the option below:

```
if ([responceStr containsString:@"tel:"]) {
        NSUInteger location = [responceStr rangeOfString:@"tel:"].location;
        NSString *subStr = [responceStr substringFromIndex:location];
        NSString *endStr;
        if ([subStr containsString:@"\">"])
        {
            NSUInteger endLocation = [subStr rangeOfString:@"\">"].location;
            endStr = [subStr substringToIndex:endLocation];
        }
        NSLog(@"New Trimed string:%@",endStr);
        responceStr = [endStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"Final Trimed string:%@",responceStr);
    }
```

You can again start searching for the next `tel:` from **endStr**.